# What is the minimum count of signatures and keys in OP_CHECKMULTISIG?

Tags: multi-signature, non-standard-transaction

Is it permissible to use `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` with 0 signatures or 0 keys? I.e. are 0-of-X or 0-of-0 outputs allowed per the protocol? Are they standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimum is 0. 0-of-0 multisigs are consensus valid, as are 0-of-n. Bare multisigs must have at least one key and signature. However it can be wrapped in a P2SH or P2WSH and will still be standard.